# A group endomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I got this statement from a book. I am trying to prove it but I am having a bit of trouble with the details. Let me explain myself.

So we start from the group $(\mathbb{R},+)$. Here we are allowed to add things. Multiplication by an integer is seen as adding $n$ times, thus we get that if $f\in \text{End}(\mathbb{R})$, then $f(nr)=f(r+r+\ldots +r)=f(r)+f(r)+\ldots +f(r)=nf(r)$. This I understand but it makes me somewhat uncomfortable, because I think we are in $(\mathbb{R},+)$ and here we are not allowed to multiply. (Or maybe we are seing it as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space?).

Now to prove that it is $\mathbb{Q}$-linear, I tried doing:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{f(a)}{m}=x&\Longleftrightarrow f(a)=xm\\
& \Longleftrightarrow f\left(m\frac{a}{m}\right)=mx\\
& \Longleftrightarrow f\left(\frac{a}{m}\right)=x.
\end{align}$$

Thus I get that the maps are $\mathbb{Q}$-linear. However in the last step I am dividing, and this is not allowed in $(\mathbb{R},+)$, although it is if we see it as a vector space. Then, does the statement mean that a group endomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear map when treated as a map from a vector space to itself?

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: Every abelian group is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, so multiplying by an integer is no problem in abelian groups.

Comment: If $n\in\Bbb N$ and $r\in\Bbb R$, then $nr$ means$$\overbrace{r+r+\cdots+r}^{n\text{ times}}.$$

Comment: Please don't rely on the titles of your MSE questions to convey important information: the body of your question should be self-contained. As for the mathematics: keep working on it as you are nearly there. You can divide in by positive integers in $(\Bbb{R}, +)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are viewing $\mathbb R$ as $\mathbb Q$-vector space. If you didn't, saying that a function $f\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is $\mathbb Q$-linear wouldn't even make sense, the very definition of $R$-linear maps assumes that you have a function between $R$-modules.

Multiplying by an integer is allowed in any abelian group, $na$ is defined as the sum $\underbrace{a+a+\cdots + a}_n$ for positive integer $n$, as $0$ if $n = 0$ and by defining $(-n)a = - (na)$, we can extend the definition to negative integers as well.
Note that this is completely analogous to writing $x^n$ in arbitrary group where we use multiplicative notation instead of the additive one. This definition turns any abelian group into a $\mathbb Z$-module.

Your proof that $\frac{f(a)}m = f\left( \frac am \right)$ is a bit sketchy in the last step, it looks like you want to pull out $m$ from the argument of $f$ and then cancel $m$'s, which works, but it would be nicer if you write that down explicitly. Alternatively, in my opinion, a nicer way to write the same thing would be
$$ m f\left(\frac 1m a\right) = f\left(m\cdot \frac 1m a\right) = f(1a) = f(a) \implies f\left(\frac 1m a\right) = \frac 1m f(a).$$